# PLSQL Replace single row with multiple results from different table

Tags: sql, oracle

I cannot seem to figure out how to achieve the result I need, and could use a hand to know if its even possible.



Assume I have the two related tables below Car Parts and Engine Parts.

Car Parts:

| Car Model | Component | Qty needed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Fasto | Fast Engine | 1 |
| Fasto | Wheels | 4 |
| Fasto | Bolts | 20 |
| Fasto | Nuts | 10 |
| Economax | Econo Engine | 1 |
| Economax | Wheels | 4 |
| Economax | Bolts | 30 |
| Economax | Nuts | 10 |

Engine Parts:

| Engine Model | Component | Qty needed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Fast Engine | Bolts | 5 |
| Fast Engine | Headers | 1 |
| Fast Engine | Cylinder Assembly | 6 |
| Econo Engine | Bolts | 8 |
| Econo Engine | Headers | 1 |
| Econo Engine | Cylinder Assmbly | 4 |

I need to have a query that products the complete list of parts required to build each car, replacing the engine with the components required to build the engine. Example result in the case of the "Fasto" car below.

| Car Model | Component | Qty needed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Fasto | Bolts | 5 |
| Fasto | Headers | 1 |
| Fasto | Cylinder Assembly | 6 |
| Fasto | Wheels | 4 |
| Fasto | Bolts | 20 |
| Fasto | Nuts | 10 |

Then I know I can group the results after etc. I hope this is clear enough to get some help (Also can't seem to get the format for tables working even though it looks fine in the preview... Sorry first post heh...)

Comment: PL/SQL is the programming language. I think you just need an SQL query.

Comment: Sorry, in case I was unclear (still figuring this out); yes that's what I am asking for. An SQL query that will achieve the results I want (specifically within the confines of what can be done on an oracle database. Since I know there are some slight differences between PLSQL,T-SQL,mySQL etc).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like *outer join* to me, along with `NVL` function. Here's what I mean:

- sample data from lines #1 - 14 (you already have that in your tables and do not type it)
- query you might be interested in begins at line #15

---

```
SQL> with
  2  car_parts (car_model, component, qty) as
  3    (select 'fasto'   , 'fast engine' ,  1 from dual union all
  4     select 'fasto'   , 'wheels'      ,  4 from dual union all
  5     select 'fasto'   , 'bolts'       , 20 from dual union all
  6     select 'fasto'   , 'nuts'        , 10 from dual union all
  7     select 'economax', 'econo engine',  1 from dual
  8    ),
  9  engine_parts (engine_model, component, qty) as
 10    (select 'fast engine' , 'bolts'            , 5 from dual union all
 11     select 'fast engine' , 'headers'          , 1 from dual union all
 12     select 'fast engine' , 'cylinder assembly', 6 from dual union all
 13     select 'econo engine', 'bolts'            , 8 from dual
 14    )
 15  select
 16    c.car_model,
 17    nvl(e.component, c.component) component,
 18    nvl(e.qty, c.qty) qty
 19  from car_parts c left join engine_parts e on e.engine_model = c.component
 20  where c.car_model = 'fasto';

CAR_MODE COMPONENT                QTY
-------- ----------------- ----------
fasto    bolts                      5
fasto    headers                    1
fasto    cylinder assembly          6
fasto    wheels                     4
fasto    nuts                      10
fasto    bolts                     20

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```